# Android studio is not opening with jdk 11

Tags: android-studio

I try to download Android studio to set up react native according to react native documentation.

I also download JDK 11.

but when I try to open Android studio, it doesn't work.

**This is from documentation**
[image]

**Error - JDK not fond when I open Android Studio**
[image]

I want to open the Android Studio.

I try all possible solutions found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Download it from the official source [here](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=CjwKCAiAzp6eBhByEiwA_gGq5PlN-4DSWR7J1m7xDjYQLlckBGbNoz_b49Z_KRRRwQ_7sqArFTQMpxoCcTkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Android studio is bundled with Java 11 so you don't need to install it separately.

Comment: I downloaded from there but in dont get oprn